# How to create an msi installation package for a database project?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, project

I am creating database project and need to create a MSI installer package. I am using VS2010. I looked around and most are using wix package. But i was looking for something more standard using MSI installer. Has someone worked on it and can help me start off with it? I have never build an MSI package before though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Visual Studio installer project has out-of-the-box Sql database installation features. You still need to write your own custom actions to execute scripts that create the database and all the required objects (tables, views, SPs, users, permissions, etc.)
Although [`Wix`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) has a steep learning curve, I think it's worth investing time and effort in it, because it is powerful and will help you in the long run. `Wix` has special elements like `SqlDatabase` or `SqlScript` that are designed for this purpose.
Some resources that might help you:

- [VS Database Guide](http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/);
- [Code Project article for Wix DB

  installation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331368/WIXDataBase);
- [Quick tutorial for

  `SqlDatabase` and `SqlScript`](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a .dacpac and deploying this using the command line?