# Prompt for user input during installation

Tags: vb.net, installation, prompt

I have developed a vb.net desktop app that connects and interacts with a database. Ideally, I would like to set up the publication project to prompt for user input during installation of the app (when running the *.msi file). Then, this input could be used as constants within the application. This way, the admins can enter the connection info during install rather than managing through config files, etc.
Prompts would include Username, Password, Database name.
Is this possible or is there a better way of implementing this functionality?

Comment: Well, you've not shared how you're creating your msi file, but normally yeah you can.  Maybe something like this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990723/how-to-create-an-msi-installation-package-for-a-database-project

Answer (score 0):

Not during install but this is how I accomplish a similar task.

Add a setting to your application called IsUpgrade and set it to true.
Create a settings form to set all of the values you need.
Once the application is installed, have the admin launch it.
Check for IsUpgrade in your starting form load event.

If IsUpgrade then
FormSettings.Show()
'Save settings in FormSettings closing event
My.Settings.IsUpgrade = False
End If